# Can I use Azure IoT Hub as a MQTT bridge?

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-suite

I have some devices that sends their data to my Azure IoT Hub. For now, a Stream analytics job processes the data, but I would also like to "forward" the data stream to an external Mosquitto server. How can I do that? Can I set up the IoT Hub to function as a MQTT Bridge?

Thanks in advance for help! (Sorry, I'm a little new to this...)

Answer (score 2):

One option: You can use Azure Functions to process the incoming data and forward it to your Mosquito server.

Comment: Thanks! I've been considering this option, but I didn't know if it was a good option or not.